# django - how to return one to many

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

this is my model

```
class plans(models.Model):
    plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    plan_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    plan_is_active = models.BooleanField(max_length=1, default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.plan_name

class plan_cat(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(plans, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cat_is_active = models.BooleanField(max_length=1, default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cat_name
```

my serializer is

```
class PlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = plans
        fields = ('plan_name','plan_price')


class CatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    plan = PlanSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = plan_cat
        fields = ('cat_name','plan')
```

this is my view

```
class plan_details(APIView):
    def get(self, requests):
        queryset = plan_cat.objects.filter(cat_is_active='1')
        serializer = CatSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

when i call this view http://localhost:8000/plans/details/

getting this output

```
[
    {
        "cat_name": "category 1",
        "plan": {
            "plan_name": "free",
            "plan_price": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "cat_name": "category 2",
        "plan": {
            "plan_name": "paid",
            "plan_price": 10
        }
    },
    {
        "cat_name": "category 3",
        "plan": {
            "plan_name": "free",
            "plan_price": 0
        }
    }
]
```

instead i want a output like this

```
[
    {
        "plan_name": "free",
        "plan_price": 0,
        "cat_name": {
            "category 1",
            "category 3",
        }
    },
    {
        "plan_name": "paid",
        "plan_price": 0,
        "cat_name": {
            "category 2",
        }
    },
]
```

the problem is the foreign key is with the second model, 
so i cant serialize to get the grouped content output as mentioned above.
do i have to rewrite the model or serializer class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reverse ralation name `plan_cat_set`. Rewrite your view and serializer to this:

```
class plan_details(APIView):
    def get(self, requests):
        queryset = plans.objects.filter(cat_is_active='1')
        serializer = PlanSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class CatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = plan_cat
        fields = ('cat_name',)

class PlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cat_name = CatSerializer(source='plan_cat_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = plans
        fields = ('plan_name','plan_price', 'cat_name')
```

Note that `source='plan_cat_set'` on `CatSerializer` allow you to change serializer field name from default plan_cat_set to `cat_name`.

Comment: thanks a lot it works, with small error: Cannot resolve keyword 'cat_is_active' into field. Choices are: id, plan_cat, plan_is_active, plan_name, plan_price, userprofile. i removed cat_is_active='1'.